# Blank arrows in \CD environment

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I am working on a DAG/diagram that should ultimately look like two squares sharing one corner.  I am having troubles progressing the code to the last two lines starting with '%':

```
$\CD
(0,0) @         >1/2>>       (1,0) @>1/3>>           (2,0) @.                  @.                  @.                  @.                 \\
      @V 1/2 VV                    @V2/3 VV                @V1 VV              @.                  @.                  @.            @.   \\
(1,1) @         >2/3>>       (2,1) @>1/2>>           (3,1) @.                  @.                  @.                  @.                 \\
      @V 1/3 VV                    @V1/2 VV                @V1 VV              @.                  @.                  @.            @.   \\  
(2,2) @         > 1 >>       (3,2) @>1/2>>           (4,2) @>1/2>>        (5,2)@>1/3>>        (6,2)@.                  @.                 \\
%     @.                           @.                      @V1/2VV             @V2/3VV             @V1 VV              @.            @.   \\
%     @.                           @.                (5,3) @>2/3>>        (6,3)@>1/2>>        (7,3)@.                  @.
\endCD
$
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure what the problem is, but if I uncomment the two lines, I get [this picture (click here)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E94qp.png)

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I wanted to see, but the code does not compile.  What do you have in the preamble?

Comment: I have `\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}` and I changed `\CD` and `\endCD` into the correct `\begin{CD}` and `\end{CD}`

Answer (score 4):

The `CD` environment is not predefined when you simply load `amsmath`. You need to also load `amscd`.

Also use `\begin{CD}` and `\end{CD}` to surround the body, not `\CD` and `\endCD`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{CD}
(0,0) @         >1/2>>       (1,0) @>1/3>>           (2,0) @.                  @.                  @.                  @.                 \\
      @V 1/2 VV                    @V2/3 VV                @V1 VV              @.                  @.                  @.            @.   \\
(1,1) @         >2/3>>       (2,1) @>1/2>>           (3,1) @.                  @.                  @.                  @.                 \\
      @V 1/3 VV                    @V1/2 VV                @V1 VV              @.                  @.                  @.            @.   \\  
(2,2) @         > 1 >>       (3,2) @>1/2>>           (4,2) @>1/2>>        (5,2)@>1/3>>        (6,2)@.                  @.                 \\
      @.                           @.                      @V1/2VV             @V2/3VV             @V1 VV              @.            @.   \\
      @.                           @.                (5,3) @>2/3>>        (6,3)@>1/2>>        (7,3)@.                  @.
\end{CD}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to switch to the more modern and powerful `tikz-cd` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em]
% first row
(0,0) \arrow[r,"1/2"] \arrow[d,"1/2"'] &
(1,0) \arrow[r,"1/3"] \arrow[d,"2/3"'] &
(2,0) \arrow[d,"1"'] \\
% second row
(1,1) \arrow[r,"2/3"] \arrow[d,"1/3"'] &
(2,1) \arrow[r,"1/2"] \arrow[d,"1/2"'] &
(3,1) \arrow[d,"1"'] \\
% third row
(2,2) \arrow[r,"1"] &
(3,2) \arrow[r,"1/2"] &
(4,2) \arrow[r,"1/2"] \arrow[d,"1/2"'] &
(5,2) \arrow[r,"1/3"] \arrow[d,"2/3"'] &
(6,2) \arrow[d,"1"'] \\
% fourth row
& &
(5,3) \arrow[r,"2/3"] &
(6,3) \arrow[r,"1/2"] &
(7,3)
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `'` after the closing `"` for the label means “swap the default position of the label”.

[image]